# Storing variables using $_SESSION

Tags: php, session-variables

What's the correct way of storing a variable within a SESSION variable? I'm trying to do this but I don't think I'm doing it right:

```
$_SESSION['queryID'] = $stID

// I want to use $stID even after the page is reloaded
if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '') {
    $stID =  $_GET['id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE State = " . $_SESSION['queryID']. ";";
```

Will using a session variable like this allow me to keep the value of $stID throughout page reloads?

Thanks

Comment: Have you added session_start to the top of the page?

Answer (score 1):

1) There is one semicolumn missing:

```
$_SESSION['queryID'] = $stID; // <<< at the end of that line
```

2) I don't see any [session_start](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) call at the top of your file. Check that you have opened a session:

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are doing it the right way. But before using the session variable value, please use isset() function.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['queryID'])) {
    $_SESSION['queryID'] = 1;
}
```

Also to use session, you will need to call session_start() function  at the very beginning of php script.

Answer (score 0):

Spotting reference is a newbie programming task, bro. PHP has a huge documentation, so read it, please.

```
$arr = array("lol"=>"roflmao");
$var =& $arr;
$var["lol"] = "roflmaobbq";

print_r($var);
/*
Array
(
    [lol] => roflmaobbq
)
*/

print_r($arr);
/*
Array
(
    [lol] => roflmaobbq
)
*/
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php

Answer (score 0):

```
//if u want to activate session use session_start()
//u didn't mention what is $stID 
//if u want to store $stID

    $_SESSION['queryID']="value"

//////////////

    <?php
    session_start();

    // I want to use $stID even after the page is reloaded
    if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] != '') {

       $_SESSION['queryID']=$_GET['id']
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE State = " . $_SESSION['queryID']. ";";

    ?>
```